# stats_date is null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, statistics, index-statistics

If I run this query on our system:

```
SELECT STATS_DATE(t.object_id, s.stats_id) AS stdate, * 
from    sys.stats s WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sys.tables t WITH (NOLOCK) ON t.object_id = s.object_id
WHERE t.name LIKE 'mytable%'
```

I **sometimes** see that the `stats_date` function returns NULL. 
This should not be possible according to BOL, except if there is an error.
It does not state which error.

The table is quite big, 11 billion rows.
If I run:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS fct.mytable ( pk_mytable)
```

the `stats_date` comes back again as not null.

Why is the date null, and how can I prevent that?

It is only the stats for the primary key that is NULL.

If I run:

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('fct.MyTable', 'IX_MyTableID')
```

it comes back with the 3 result sets that I expect.
If I run:

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('fct.MyTable', 'PK_MyTable')
```

It returns:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190330.aspx) it can return null on error, although why you would experience an error with this I am not sure. Have you considered doing an outer apply to the sys.dm_db_stats_properties function to see if you get the same results?

```
SELECT  t.name ,
        s.object_id ,
        s.stats_id ,
        c.name ,
        sc.stats_column_id ,
        s.name ,
        sp.last_updated ,
        sp.rows_sampled ,
        sp.modification_counter ,
        sp.steps ,
        sp.rows
FROM    [sys].[stats] AS [s]
        INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns sc ON s.stats_id = sc.stats_id
                                            AND s.object_id = sc.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = sc.object_id
                                    AND c.column_id = sc.column_id
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
        OUTER APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_properties([s].[object_id],
                                                [s].[stats_id]) AS [sp]
WHERE   t.name LIKE 'mytable%';
```

Comment: hi Nic,
Yes, your query return NULL values for the columns from the dm_db_stats_properties function.

Comment: If you've confirmed that none of the information in the remarks section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553546.aspx applies then I would open a Connect item as it sounds like a bug.

Comment: I'll open a case with Microsoft, as soon as the ones we currently have are fixed.

Comment: It looks as if this SO item describes the problem; http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111590/statistics-disappear-after-incremental-update

Comment: We have just applied SP1 CU2, and it looks as if the problem has been fixed.